# How to install gems for non-default Ruby with Puppet?

Tags: redhat, puppet, centos6, gem

The ruby included with RedHat/CentOS-6 is of version 1.8.7, which is too old for many applications. Though simply updating it with a custom-built RPM is possible, my colleagues shy away from the idea and wish to use the [rh-ruby22](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-ruby22/) packages available from the [SCL-repo](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL).

That installs ruby-2.2, which is great, but under `/opt/rh/rh-ruby22`. I now need to install several gems and would like to, obviously, use Puppet:

```
package {'example':
  ensure   => '0.25',
  provider => 'gem'
}
```

Unfortunately, the gem-provider invokes `/usr/bin/gem` instead of `/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/bin/gem` that needs to be invoked. Is there any other way? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use [sensu's yum repository](https://sensuapp.org/docs/0.25/platforms/sensu-on-rhel-centos.html#sensu-core)?

Comment: "Sensu" was just an example here. Obviously...

Comment: That's not obvious at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [package](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/package.html) resource, and in particular the [gem](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/package.html#package-provider-gem) [provider](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/package.html#package-attribute-provider), now supports the use of the [`command` attribute](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/package.html#package-attribute-command). Your particular example is now supported like this:

```ruby
package {'example':
  ensure   => '0.25',
  provider => 'gem',
  command  => '/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/bin/gem'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the "easy" way is to implement one's own package-provider. Fortunately, one can inherit everything from the existing gem-provider overriding only the gem-command itself.

Because SCL's rh-ruby22 is so retarded, you can't even invoke its `ruby` or `gem` directly -- without setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` first -- we create wrappers for them in `/usr/bin`. The `/usr/bin/gem2`, for example, sets the library path (and `PATH`) and then `exec`s the real `/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/bin/gem` with its own arguments (`"$@"`).

My new provider uses the `gem2` wrapper script to do its thing.

I created the file `gem2.rb` in `modules/SOMEMODULE/lib/puppet/provider/package/` with the following content (tested with Puppet-3.8.7):

```ruby
require 'puppet/provider/package'

Puppet::Type.type(:package).provide File.basename(__FILE__, ".rb"),
    :parent => :gem, :source => :gem do
        desc "Ruby Gem support using #{@name}-executable"

        commands :gemcmd => @name.to_s
end
```

Though I was hoping, my implementation would allow one to specify the gem-command as a parameter in the puppet-manifest, it is impossible to do this without completely rewriting the existing gem-provider. My way is much easier and just as efficient.

As a bonus, copying the file to some other name (such as `gem19.rb`) will automatically create the new provider -- just be sure, `gem19` is in the `$PATH`.

The module, under which you'll save this file, can be *any* module used by the machine(s) that need the new provider.